# Plain HTTP API call to Google Geocoding API fails with Python requests module

Tags: python, google-maps, ssl, google-geocoding-api

I'm inside a corporate proxy, so often I have SSL issues and have to fall back to plain HTTP (when it's not an issue involving sensitive data). Thus, I'm trying to geotag with [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding) over plain HTTP. When I craft a call and execute it with `curl` on the terminal, I get my JSON resonse as expected. But, when I put the same URL inside a Python script and hit the URL with `requests.get`, I get an SSL error:

```
{u'status': u'REQUEST_DENIED', u'error_message': u'Requests to this API must be over SSL.', u'results': []}
```

The Python is dead-simple, but here it is for posterity:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=some+address+here&key=my-key')
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

print json_data
```

And, of course, if I try the call with HTTPS I run in to proxy cert errors. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:

I know I can add the `verify=false` flag to the `requests` method call to overcome the SSL cert issue, but that doesn't help me understand why the call is bouncing off the API even though it ostensibly accepts plain HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the http**s** protocol for your request

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=some+address+here&key=my-key')
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

print json_data
```

The example url from the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro):
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=my_key

gives

> {u'status': u'OK', u'results': [{u'geometry': {u'location': {u'lat': 37.422245, u'lng': -122.0840084}, u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 37.42359398029149, u'lng': -122.0826594197085}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 37.4208960197085, u'lng': -122.0853573802915}}, u'location_type': u'ROOFTOP'}, u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'1600', u'types': [u'street_number'], u'short_name': u'1600'}, {u'long_name': u'Amphitheatre Parkway', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Amphitheatre Pkwy'}, {u'long_name': u'Mountain View', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Mountain View'}, {u'long_name': u'Santa Clara County', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Santa Clara County'}, {u'long_name': u'California', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'CA'}, {u'long_name': u'United States', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'US'}, {u'long_name': u'94043', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'94043'}], u'place_id': u'ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA', u'formatted_address': u'1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', u'types': [u'street_address']}]}

Comment: I understand that these API calls should be made over HTTPS. However, as I stated above in my OP, I'm running into proxy/cert issues that have led me to try making the calls over plain HTTP. And the docs for the API state that this is possible: "To access the Google Maps Geocoding API over HTTP, use: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters`".